# Lib usb how to read character from port

Tags: c++, c, linux, usb, libusb

I want to write an application that reads data from the USB device and was looking for a library that can make the job easier. I found a library called `lib-usb`. Unfortunately, it has almost no documentation. Here is what I have tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <usb.h>

     int main(){
        struct usb_device dev;
        struct usb_device *device;
        usb_dev_handle *handle;
        struct usb_bus bus;

usb_init();
            usb_find_busses();
            int a=usb_find_devices();
        bus=usb_get_buses();
        handle=usb_open(device);

            return 0;
        }
```

But I can't figure out how to select a port that I want to read from. I would like to save read data as a string. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Did you just have a stroke while typing that last bit?

Comment: I think you need to rephrase the question...

Comment: Your (presumably) machine translator is producing incomprehensible output. I would recommend that you find a different translation tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USB doesn't really transfer characters -- it transfers packets. Additionally, your code makes no sense at all; there is some pretty good documentation online at http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/, which I recommend that you read.